# Creating a table without creating a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a constraint about creating tables on a db that I want to run a query on.  DB system is Postgres

I can do the following:

```
testdb=# select 'john' as first, 'doe' as last;                                          
 first | last 
-------+------
 john  | doe
```

but what I want to be able to do is:

```
 first | last 
-------+------
 john  | doe
 jane  | doe
```

So, I can produce the first row, but not the subsequent row

Alternatively, is there a way to ensure that a temporary table is removed if my session with the database is lost?

Cheers

Adam

Comment: Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html#AEN67422

Comment: this comment system is horrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest (most compact) form is a row constructor:

```
select * 
from ( 
   values 
      ('John', 'Doe'), 
      ('Jane', 'Doe'), 
      ('Arthur', 'Dent')
) as t (first, last)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
WITH testdb(first,last) AS (VALUES ('john','doe'), ('jane', 'doe')) 
SELECT * FROM testdb;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2296/0)

> WITH provides a way to write auxiliary statements for use in a larger
>   query. These statements, which are often referred to as Common Table
>   Expressions or CTEs, can be thought of as defining temporary tables
>   that exist just for one query. Each auxiliary statement in a WITH
>   clause can be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE; and the WITH clause
>   itself is attached to a primary statement that can also be a SELECT,
>   INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.